# What is App Emulation In magento

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, app, environment-emulation

I want to know what is app emulation in magento...
I saw its forcefully set store id ....in store...but why this is use in magento..
I use this in my project..but i want to know Detail about App Emulation..

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(0);
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the biggest feature Magento is famous for is its capabilities to develop multi-store and multi-language web stores. Each store can be completely different from its fellow stores. Store Emulation helps developers to emulate any store programmatically.

Suppose you want to send custom transactional e-mail for all stores at the same time as cronjob. When a process run on backend for example cron jobs or email notifications, these processes work under admin store. But suppose if you want to send transactional e-mail on store wise, then email template need grab from store view. You can enable App Emulation and perform this action.

```
Ex:
    $storeId = 1;
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

    // Start environment emulation of the specified store
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    /*
     * Any code thrown here will be executed as currently running that store
     * with applied locale, design and similar
     */

    // Stop environment emulation and restore original store
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Comment: What if we use `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($order->getStoreId());` to send list of products in an order and send email through observer. would this be the same as emulation?

Comment: How can i maintain different QTY in same sku in magento multi-store?